# Code explanation, what doing this code for shuffling

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone describe to me what the code does step by step?
and what doing this? const { length } = data;

```
getQuestions: async (req, res) => {
const data = await Question.find();
const { length } = data;
const ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ids.push(i)
}
const idsTrimmed = ids.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 2)
const ans = []
idsTrimmed.forEach(id => {
  ans.push(data[id])
})
res.send(ans)
```

},

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what is the schema of the **Question** collection. The length must be one of the property of the collection and by doing `cost {length} = data`  you are extracting that value of length property. This is called as **Object De-structuring** .

Answer (score 1):

I divide the code to some blocks and add comment for each block.

```
getQuestions: async (req, res) => {

// query the database to get the list of questions
const data = await Question.find();

// create an array that contains the list of question index in the array
const { length } = data;
const ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ids.push(i)
}

// shuffle the index array, then select 2 first elements
const idsTrimmed = ids.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 2)

// get back the question using index
const ans = []
idsTrimmed.forEach(id => {
  ans.push(data[id])
})

// send to client
res.send(ans)
```

(Not directly related to your question, but the code could be improved for clarity, below is my suggestion)

```
getQuestionsRandomly : async (req, res) {

  const NB_QUESTIONS_SELECTED = 2;
  const allQuestions = await Question.find();
  
  const questionIndexes = allQuestions.map((item, index) => index);

  const randomIndexes = questionIndexes.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
                                       .slice(0, NB_QUESTIONS_SELECTED);

 
  const randomQuestions = randomIndexes.map(item => allQuestions[item]);

  res.send(randomQuestions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getQuestions: async (req, res) => {
// Calling Question.Find function to get some data back
const data = await Question.find();

// Extract the length prop/object from the data
const { length } = data;

// Setup the ids based on the length of the data
const ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ids.push(i)
}

// Shuffle the ids and take first 2 
const idsTrimmed = ids.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 2)

//build up the ans array and return to the getQuestion function caller.
const ans = []
idsTrimmed.forEach(id => {
  ans.push(data[id])
})
res.send(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = await Question.find();
```

We started by retrieving some questions and storing them in a variable called `data`.

```
const { length } = data;
```

This is called [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Basically this is shorthand for `const length = data.length`.

```
const ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ids.push(i)
}
```

This is creating an array called `ids` which contains the numbers `0` through `length - 1` which corresponds to all the valid indexes in `data`.

```
const idsTrimmed = ids.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 2)
```

This is shuffling and truncating the `ids` array.

The array [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method takes a function as an argument which allows for a custom sorting order. That function is passed a pair of elements from the array and should return a negative number if the first argument comes before the second in the sorted order, a positive number if the second argument comes before the first, or 0 if the two arguments are equal. `Math.random` returns a random number between 0 and 1, so by subtracting 0.5, we get negative numbers and positive numbers roughly 50% of the time each. Since each element is put before or after another at random, we're effectively shuffling the array.

The [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method copies and truncates the array to the items after and including index 0 but before index 2. Essentially, it's creating a new array with just the first 2 elements from the shuffled array.

```
const ans = []
idsTrimmed.forEach(id => {
  ans.push(data[id])
})
```

And here we take our 2 random indexes from the previous step and grab the elements from `data` with those indexes. Since the indexes were shuffled, we know these are two random items.